# Alexa Confirmation of Number

Tags: numbers, alexa-slot

I ask the user for a number for a slot and then want to confirm the number.  The numbers are seven digits(e.g., 5433975).

Alexa confirms by saying the number as a value rather than saying each digit.

I have tried '{acblNumber}  right' for the confirmation and it does not work.

I hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must send speech output as SSML type:

```
speechOutput = "<say-as interpret-as='digits'>5433975</say-as>"
```

Comment: My original post got garbled.  The prompt for slot confirnation is:


"is <say-as interpret-as='spell-out'>{acblNumber} </say-as> correct"

and the SSML gets spoken out in the prompt.

Comment: is 'spell-out' working? If it doesn't then use 'digits' instead.